# Spark - Replace column value - regex pattern value is having slash value- how to handle it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Data Frame:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|               Desc|   replaced_columns|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|India is my Country|India is my Country|
| Delhi is my Nation| Delhi is my Nation|
| I Love India\Delhi| I Love India\Delhi|
|         I Love USA|         I Love USA|
|I am stay in USA\SA|I am stay in USA\SA|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

"Desc" column is the original column name from DataFrame. replace_columns is after we are doing some transformation. In desc column , i need to replace "India\Delhi" value to "-". I tried below code.

```
dataDF.withColumn("replaced_columns", regexp_replace(dataDF("Desc"), "India\\Delhi", "-")).show()
```

it is NOT replacing with "-" string. How can i do that one ?

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 approaches for the above question:

```
val approach1 = dataDF.withColumn("replaced_columns", regexp_replace(col("Desc"), "\\\\","-")).show() // (it should be 4 backslash in actual while running in IDE)

val approach2 = dataDF.select($"Desc",translate($"Desc","\\","-").as("replaced_columns")).show()
```

The below one is for specific record which you asked above -- ( In `desc` column , I need to replace `"India\Delhi"` value to `"-"`. I tried below code.)

```
val approach3 = dataDF
   .withColumn("replaced_columns",when(col("Desc").like("%Delhi")
     , regexp_replace(col("Desc"), "\\\\", "-")).otherwise(col("Desc")))
    .show()
```

Comment: replace - "\\\\" to "-" - would NOT be the right solution.. it will cause other text string which is having "\" character..

Comment: try with approach 2

Comment: it worked in my IDE. So copied the same. Don't know why it didn't worked for you

Comment: for example "having 2\3 inc." is one the column value.. it is got changed to "having 2-3 inc". so we couldn;t apply this transformation,